# Retrieve task from sock

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am currently developing a Linux kernel module.

My module has a callback for the net_dev_xmit tracepoint event.

One of the parameters of such tracepoint is the struct sk_buff *skb.

My question is the following: how can one retrieve the task struct of the
thread that generated the packet that the kernel is going to emit?
Is there any guarantee that the such thread is the "current" one?